# Envio formulario para dois arquivos php

Tags: php, html, formulário

Tenho uma duvida curiosa e talvez idiota, mas vamos lá.

É possível enviar os dados de um formulário para dois arquivos diferentes em php?

Comment: Seja um pouco mais especifico você quer que os dados digitados de um formulário preencham 2 bancos de dados diferentes??

Comment: Sim vai alimentar bancos diferentes ao mesmo tempo com um único formulário.

Comment: Se quiser a falar de duas `actions` do form, não creio que seja possivel

Comment: ok vou pesquisar deve haver algum resolução possível obrigado a todos se eu encontrar uma solução vou escrever aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando PHP: Dá para enviar via post ou get para um arquivo (controller), que tratará e distribuirá os dados para os 2 arquivos distintos (models).

Usando JAVASCRIPT: Dá para você pegar os campos que quiser e enviar (via post ou get) para arquivos diferentes via AJAX.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Como disse o Alan, isso é possível via AJAX.

Mesmo não conhecendo as tuas necessidades, posso afirmar que o mais "barato" será sempre fazer o processamento todo **num único script** PHP no lado do servidor.